# fastest way to make a new column holding the k-trailing min of another column

Tags: python, pandas, minimum, trailing

I have a python pandas DataFrame with very large columns.  For one of the columns (call it column A), I need the fast possible way to make a new column (call it column E) or separate series.  The elements of new column E are determined based on the values in column A.  In column E, each element is set by reference to the corresponding element of column A and  replacing it with the minimum of the element and the k values that preceded it in A.  I must iterate this process many times, so speed is my concern.

As an example, if k were equal to 2, and this were my data frame:

```
   A  B  
 v 10 10  
 w 4  8  
 x 11  1     
 y 9  22  
 z 15 5
```

I would want to create the following column E based on column A

```
    E
 v  10
 w  4
 x  4
 y  4
 z  9
```

To simplify the problem, I could also except this result:

```
    E
 v  NaN
 w  NaN
 x  4
 y  4
 z  9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.rolling_min` and set `window=k+1` to calculate the rolling minimum with a lookback window of `k+1`.

```
pd.rolling_min(df['A'], window=3)

v   NaN
w   NaN
x     4
y     4
z     9
dtype: float64
```